# Prove that if $ a,b,c > 0$, then if $ax^{2} + bx + c = 0$ has real solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

Prove that if $ a,b,c > 0$, then if $ax^{2} + bx + c = 0$ has real solutions, both solutions are negative. I want to prove this by contradiction.

Proof: If we let $a,b,c = 1$, we have $x^{2} + x + 1 = 0$

or $x^{2} + x = -1$. If $x$ is positive the sum of two positive terms can not be $< 0$

hence $x$ must be negative. But no matter the $x$ we pick there will be no solution to $x^{2} + x = -1$.

So $a,b,c$ must also be $ < 0$. If $a,b,c < 0$ we have $-ax^{2} -bx -c = 0$

or  $-ax^{2} -bx = c$. If $x$ is positive then resulting equation is $negative - negative = positive$, which is not possible. So $x$ must be negative.

Have I shown by contradiction, both solutions are negative? How can I improve my answer?

Comment: the statement the title asks to prove is not true

Comment: @J.W Tanner There is no statement in the title.

Comment: @uniquesolution:  You're right; I didn't see the second "if" on my first read of the title; סליחה

Comment: @J.W.Tanner 没关系

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r_1,r_2$ be the real roots. Then $r_1+r_2=-\frac{b}{a}$ and $r_1r_2=\frac{c}{a}$.
Since $c/a>0$, both roots have the same sign, but $-b/a<0$ so they both must be negative.

Comment: Vieta's formula.

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct. A proof by contradiction would be as follows: if $r$ is a root of $ax^2+bx+c$ and $r\geqslant0$, then $ar^2+br+c=0$. But this is not true, because $ar^2+br+c\geqslant c>0$. Therefore $r<0$.

You should keep in mind that proving it form a single polynomial ($x^2+x+1$, in your case) doesn't prove it in general.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

Let $D = b^2 - 4ac ~\implies~$ the roots are

$$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{D}}{2a}.$$

Confine attention to the numerator.

Since it is assumed that both roots real, and that $a,b,c > 0:$

$$b > |\sqrt{D}| \geq 0.$$

Therefore, both $(-b + \sqrt{D})$ and $(-b - \sqrt{D})$ are negative.